# Querying date from and date to on same day returns no rows

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have two datepickers whose dates are to be used in this query:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
        select * from TotalBill 
        where SaudaDate between 
                 convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "') 
             and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "')"
                       , con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
gvDailyBill.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

When I want to query for one day, I cannot set both datepickers to the same day, but I have to set the `From` to the day I want and the `To` to a day beyond. If I don't, the query becomes something like this:

```
select * from totalbill where SaudaDate between '1/2/2013' and '1/2/2013'
```

Which of course returns 0 rows. How do I alter my code or query to allow the selection of the same day in the datepickers?

Comment: This is really too vague. What is the problem? Date formatting? String building? Query execution? Also your _"but i wanted it to be"_ is the same, twice.

Comment: [Please update your title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: if you read the question you will understand problem

Comment: Did you store also the time part in the SaudeDate field?

Comment: in first "but i wanted it to be:" i have shown it with datetime picker and in second one i have shown it with query

Comment: **USE ... PARAMETERIZED ... QUERIES!!!** This not only prevents SQL injections, but also uses the correct data types so that internationalization issues are minimized. How often does that have to be repeated...

Comment: @Steve yes every thing is stored in db

Comment: I have read the question and I do not understand the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: my problem is that while making datewise search when both dates are same, (from and to) it should show the date for those corrosponding dates. but it is not

Comment: I have edited question, please have a look at it

Comment: I have edited your question into something readable.

Comment: oh!, do you mean that you want your first argument to be `00:00:01` and your second argument `23:59:59`, so that you get the whole day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Query must be like below...

```
"select * from TotalBill 
        where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SaudaDate, 101) between 
                 convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "') 
             and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "')"
```

`SaudaDate` is in Date time format.... So it may be like this `'1/2/2013 07:54:00'`

and if you convert this like `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SaudaDate, 101)` then it will become `'1/2/2013 00:00:00'`

Now it will give you the result you needed..

Try it...

Comment: wanted to know what is 101 in between?? CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SaudaDate, 101) @Pandian

Comment: @Freelancer : 101 is a Format Type, you can refer this site for all the formats... http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: 101 represents a particular dateformat. Here is a list of formats. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: This converts all dates in the column prior to querying, which is slow and should not be used. Just add a day to the TO date...

Comment: @CodeCaster : I just answer a solution for that query... i think you still don't understand the question and my solution... if you say it slow down the process.. then you provide a good solution to him....

Comment: I now perfectly understand the question, and I understand your solution too. Unfortunately, it does work and is accepted, while it is not quite the best solution. Others have suggested better solutions. But you're now saying _"if you don't provide an answer you can't say my answer is crap"_, which lucily is not how this site works.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I know how the site works... ***Some of the persons like you just comments on all the solutions and didn't provide any good answers to OP...*** if you have a good solution better than this then just post that as Answer.... that what i am saying...

Comment: @CodeCaster I agree with you. Pandian, instead of taking a defensive stance, why not try to learn from what CodeCaster has to say? I don't think he's saying "this is wrong" because he wants to put blame on you, he's saying it so that we all can learn to be better programmers. That is why he comments instead of answers, because this answer can be improved to show a better solution. At least that's what I do when I comment instead of answer (I could be wrong).

Answer (score 3):

Important first :
[You need parametrized query.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
var fromDate = dtpForDate.Value.Date;
var toDate = dtpToDate.Value.Date;

string selectSQL = "select * from TotalBill where SaudaDate between @start and @end";
da = new SqlDataAdapter();         

SqlCommand selectCMD = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
da.SelectCommand = selectCMD;

selectCMD.Parameters.Add("@start ", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fromDate;
selectCMD.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = toDate;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
gvDailyBill.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Secondly, you filter by date. But when your start date is equal to your end date, you want the datas of all the day.
What if the start date and the end date are different ? Do you want to include all the values of the end date too?

When you say "01/01/2010" to Sql, it understand "01/01/2010 00:00:00". You can't filter by date, but you filter by date**time**. This is an important difference.

So in your case, the right query is I think :

```
var fromDate = dtpForDate.Value.Date;
var toDate = dtpToDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1); // trick, add one day
```

In this case, when fromDate == toDate == '1/2/2013', you will get all the datas between '1/2/2013 00:00:00' and '1/3/2013' 00:00:00'. In pure english, you will get all the datas of the day 1/2/2013.

Comment: While absolutely true, this is not an answer to the question as it will not solve OP's problem.

Comment: How does this answer his question?? This only prevents SQL injection and introduces better programming style, but that's it.. His question is quite different...

Comment: yeah, this query is same as i have wrote it, only style is different

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to include the dates then dont use between. Use greater/less than or equal.

```
select * from totalbill where SaudaDate >= '2013-02-01' and SaudaDate <= '2013-02-01'
```

Edit. If your date column is actually a datetime which has times other than 00:00:00.000 then you will need to use the "Like" in your where for a single date.

```
select * from totalbill where SaudaDate like '2013-02-01%'
```

Or you will need to add a single day to the second date programatically.

```
select * from totalbill where SaudaDate >= '2013-02-01' and SaudaDate <= '2013-02-02'
```

Comment: Are your date fields just a date or are they datetime?

Comment: datetime eg. 2013-03-21 09:21:20.000

Comment: @Freelancer Well that is your issue.Your dateformat is wrong. Your date in the select should be '2013-02-01' not '1/2/2013'

Comment: Just thought of another issue. Because your using DateTime your dates can be up to 23:59 per day. By specifying only the date this assumes 2013-03-21 00:00:00.000.

Comment: Between will only do what the word means. Between two dates. You will need to programatically change the SQL for a single date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `SaudaDate` to only date part.
Try following:

```
try
{
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
            select * from TotalBill 
            where Cast(Convert(varchar(20),SaudaDate,101) as Datetime) between 
                     convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "') 
                 and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "')"
                           , con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    gvDailyBill.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
catch (Exception ex){}
```

This code will work for the same day selection too.

Comment: yes, i have already done that if you can see my current query

Comment: I am talking about SaudaDate column.

Comment: use Cast(Convert(varchar(20),SaudaDate,101) as Datetime) in place of SaudaDate. This will definitly work for you. 101 return only date part and this is what you need to compare in order to get same date range records.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested,

You need to change your SQL query

```
select * from TotalBill 
    where SaudaDate >=@yourDateFrom 
AND SaudaDate<=@yourDateTo
```